# Prove that the graph is connected

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, connectedness

I was wondering if someone can help me understand how prove that this graph is connected.

Given a graph with n vertices, prove that if the degree of each vertex is at least $(n − 1)/2$ then the graph is connected.

So far I know that about connected graphs:

An undirected graph is called **connected** if there is a path between
every pair of distinct vertices of the graph

The **distance** between two vertices in a graph is the length of
the shortest path between them.

The **diameter** of a graph is the distance between the two vertices
that are farthest apart.

---

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/927151/proving-graph-connectedness-given-the-minimum-degree-of-all-vertices

Comment: @BhaskarVashishth I checked that out, it didn't help me, but thanks.

Comment: Note that, if $n$ is even, the graph is not just connected but, by Dirac's theorem, it has a Hamiltonian cycle.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Call the $n$-vertex graph $G$. Choose any two vertices $u,v \in V(G)$. We want to find a $(u,v)$-path. Now if $u = v$ or $uv \in E(G)$, then we are done. So we may assume that $u \neq v$ and $uv \notin E(G)$. We will prove the stronger claim that there is some path of the form $u \to w \to v$ for some $w \in V(G)$.

Consider the neighbourhoods of each endpoint:
\begin{align*}
A &= \{a \in V(G) \mid ua \in E(G)\} \\
B &= \{b \in V(G) \mid vb \in E(G)\}
\end{align*}
It suffices to show that these neighbourhoods overlap (if they do, then we can just pick any $w \in A \cap B$ and we are done). Indeed, observe that:
\begin{align*}
|A \cap B|
&= |A| + |B| - |A \cup B| \\
&= \deg(u) + \deg(v) - |A \cup B| \\
&\geq \frac{n - 1}{2} + \frac{n - 1}{2} - (n - 2) \\
&= 1
\end{align*}
Hence, we conclude that $A\cap B \neq \varnothing$, as desired. $~~\blacksquare$

Comment: thanks! so what are standard formulas that I should I know when I approach questions likes these?

Comment: The only formula I used here was the set theoretic inclusion-exclusion formula for counting stuff in unions/intersections. The main trick used here was to associate "degrees" with "neighbourhoods" and to think about how we could force a **common neighbour**. This is a standard graph theory trick.

Comment: This looks very complicated. Is something wrong with David's/my answer?

Comment: @StefanPochmann It is precisely the same argument. My approach is direct, whereas yours and David's is by contradiction.

Comment: Brilliant answer. On a slightly related note, are there properties that allow one to prove a component of a graph? (Say graph G(V,E), and we want to show that a subset S of V and Q of E form a component of G? Assuming of course that S and Q do represent a connected graph)

Comment: In order to associate "degree of vertex" with the "neighbourhood of its vertices", aren't we assuming that the graph is simple (i.e no double edges)? In general $|A| \leq \deg(u)$.

Answer (score 7):

Proof:

*If each degree is at least that, then each component has at least one vertex and $\frac{n-1}{2}$ others, so at least $\frac{n-1}{2}+1=\frac{n+1}{2}$ vertices. Two components would have at least twice as many vertices, which is n+1, more than the graph has.*

(I realize this is the same as David's, but I don't like unnecessary variables so I feel it's still worth posting.)

Edit: Different wording, appropriate for the OP's stated terminology/knowledge:

Alternative proof:

*Take any two vertices. Each has at least $\frac{n-1}{2}$ neighbors. If there were no path between our two vertices, then the two neighborhoods must be separate and we'd have at least $2\cdot(1+\frac{n-1}{2})=n+1$ vertices, more than the graph has.*

Answer (score 6):

suppose the graph has at least two distinct connected components, $C_1$ and $C_2$. denote by $c_1,c_2$ two vertices, one in each component.

$C_1$ has the vertex $c_1$ and at least $\frac{n-1}2$ other vertices, one for each edge incident to $c_1$, a total of at least $\frac{n+1}2$. likewise $C_2$ must have at least $\frac{n+1}2$ vertices.

the graph must therefore have at least
$$
\frac{n+1}2 + \frac{n+1}2 = n+1
$$
 vertices, contradicting the assumption

Answer (score 3):

I think this can be done by induction on the number of vertices: this is trivially true for $n=1,2$. Assume true for $n=k$, i.e., every graph on $k$ vertices where each vertex has degree $\geq (k-1)/2 ; k>2 $ ,is path-connected.

Now consider a graph $S_{k+1}$ on $k+1 $ vertices. Isolate any subgraph $S_k$ with $k$ vertices, and define $v_{k+1}:= S_{k+1}-S_k$, i.e., $v_{k+1}$ is just the vertex of $S_k$ thatis not in $S_{k+1}$ (EDIT : ignore edges out of/into $v_{k+1})$ . By induction, $S_k$ is path-connected. We know $Deg(v_{k+1}) \geq (k+1-1)/2=k/2 $. But now we just need
$Deg(v_{k+1}) \geq 1 $ . Now join $v_{k+1}$ with any $v_j ; j \neq k+1$, which gives you, by path-connectedness of $S_k$ a path between $v_{k+1}$ and $v_j$;
$k+1 \neq j$.

EDIT   Alternatively, consider a path-connected graph on $k-1$ vertices, with $Deg(v_j) \geq (k-1)/2$ . Throw in a new vertex $v_{k+1}$ and draw  and edge between $v_{k+1}$ and every other edge, and you have a path-connected graph with $Deg(v_j)=(k-1)/2+1 =(k+1)/2 \geq k/2$

Comment: "Isolate any subgraph $S_k$ with $k$ vertices [...]. By induction, $S_k$ is path-connected."

Comment: Because every vertex in $S_k$ has degree at least $k/2$, satisfying the induction hypothesis, i.e., it is a graph on $k$ vertices and at least $(k-1)/2$ edges. What is wrong with that?

Comment: My comment was indeed wrong, I apologise. But why is the minimal degree in $S_k$ at least $(k-1)/2$? I only see $(k+1-1)/2 -1 =(k-1)/2 - 1/2$.

Comment: Indeed I can have a graph on $3$ vertices with each vertex of degree $1$ and remove a vertex so that the remaining graph is not connected.

Comment: No problem. Let me double check.

Comment: Sorry, I have to head out now, I will be back later and will try to tighten p; if I cannot, I will delete. Did you see the bottom edited paragraph?

Comment: And I made another mistake, I should not try to do maths today. I meant a graph with two vertices of degree one and one of degree two. But still.

Comment: You can always cover the cases for n=1,2,3 separately, since these are simple. Still, I will try to write a more general response.