# Given a graph $G$, prove (by contradiction) that if $\delta(G) \ge \frac{n}{2}$, then $G$ is connected.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, proof-verification

There is a similar problem [here,](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/295527/proof-regarding-connected-graphs-with-even-number-of-vertices) but I am looking to prove this statement by contradiction, and I am having difficulty understanding these solutions.

Here is what I've got so far.

> Proof.
>   Let $G$ be a graph with $n$ vertices such that $\delta(G) \ge n/2$.
>   Suppose for the sake of contradiction that $G$ is disconnected. 
>   Let H be the smallest component of G. 
>   Then $|H| \le n/2$.

From here, I know my general direction - I need to determine how many vertices, at most, can be in $H$ - which should conflict with what we know about $\delta(G)$.

Can anyone show me how to move forward with this idea?

Comment: What is $\delta$?

Comment: @AdamHughes Are you just asking this generally? $\delta$ is the least degree in the graph.

Comment: Can you prove that $|H|\le n/2$? And from that can you show that a vertex in $H$ has degree $\lt n/2$?

Comment: You can't suppose that $n=2c$ (i.e., that $n$ is even), can you?

Comment: Isn't the direct proof it much simpler? - Pick two vertices $a,b$. Each has at least $\frac n2$ neigbours, hence they have a neighbour in common?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen My intention of this is to avoid the use of typical division, which I am not allowed to do in my proof.

Comment: @bof Why $|H| \le n/2$? Is this simply because H is a component of G?

Comment: It's because, if you take a set of $n$ elements (the vertices of $G$) and divide it into two or more parts (the components), the smallest part will have at most half the elements. More generally, if you divide an $n$-element set into $k$ parts, the smallest part will have $\le n/k$ elements.

Comment: What is "typical division" and why aren't you allowed to use it?

Comment: "Typical division" is referring to the notation $\frac{x}{y}$. I must use the definition of division (i.e. $a$ is divisible by $b$ provided there is an integer $c$ such that $a = bc$) instead of that notation.

Comment: @dewick49 yes, one usually explains their notation.

Comment: It hardly seems fair that you can't refer to the notation $\frac xy.$ How can you even refer to the hypothesis of the problem, which contains the notation $\frac n2$?

Comment: Of course HagenvonEitzen's suggestion is much better than mine, since it shows that the diameter of the graph is at most $2.$

Comment: @bof Can you elaborate a bit more on what you were saying about a vertex in $H$ having a degree $< n/2$?

Comment: I caught that and edited my comment shortly before you replied. Sorry!

Comment: Suppose $v\in H.$ The degree of $v$ is the number of neighbors of $v$ (I assume we're talking about a *simple* graph). Since $H$ is a component, a vertex in $H$ can't be adjacent to a vertex not in $H$; therefore all the neighbors of $v$ are in $H.$ Since $v$ is not a neighbor of itself, $$\operatorname{degree}(v)\le|H|-1\le\frac n2-1\lt\frac n2.$$

Comment: Because $G$ is disconnected, it has at least two components, so the smallest component contains at most $n/2$ vertices. If $G$ is connected then there is only one component and it's the whole graph.

Comment: I'm deleting and rephrasing my previous comment: Ah, alright. I see the connection here. Thanks for putting that together. However, what's the contradiction? Is it that $G$ is now connected, or is the contradiction with the fact that my first assumption was $\delta(G) \ge n/2$? Is this contradiction proof still valid even though it doesn't necessarily say that "$G$ is connected," but rather shows that $d(v) < n/2$? If that makes sense. Or am I still missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\delta(G)\geqslant\frac n2$ but $G$ is not connected, then each component of $G$ must have at least $\left\lceil\frac n2\right\rceil+1$ vertices. But this means $G$ has at least $n+2$ vertices, a contradiction.